# UIWebView genera una excepción cuando uso [WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

Cuando corro mi aplicacion utilizando iOS 8, veo que la siguiente excepcion es generada dentro de la implementación de UIWebView:

```
[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167ee900

* WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:willRemoveScrollingLayer:withContentsLayer:forNode: delegate: -[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:
```

Esto ocurre cuando cambio algunas de las restricciones de NSLayoutConstraints  de mi `UIWebView`:

```
self.webViewWidthConstraints.constant = newWidth;
[self.webView setNeedsLayout]
[self.webView layoutIfNeeded];
```

(Hago esto para que el contenido del UIWebView vuelva a ser dibujado por UIKit para que quepa dentro de la anchura de mi UIWebView correctamente)

Por suerte, la excepción es ignorada, por lo tanto la aplicación no se cuelga.

¿Por qué ocurre esto, y hay alguna manera de prevenirlo?

> **Pregunta original**: [UIWebView throwing exception for [WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894173/uiwebview-throwing-exception-for-webactiondisablingcalayerdelegate-setbeingremo)

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se hizo en SO en inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25894173/135050 y tiene varias respuestas. Parece ser una traducción de la misma.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino de hecho es una traducción de la misma pregunta, probablemente el usuario busca aquí alguien que pudiera dar otra opinion. =0!

Comment: No hay ninguna regla en el sitio que prohíbe traducciones.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Es verdad, no hay nada que prohiba traducciones. Ahora, ¿cuál es el objetivo de hacer eso?. Primero que nada, si es una traducción, debería tener una referencia a la pregunta original (ahora fue editada y ya la tiene). Y luego, si ya tiene respuesta en SO en inglés, ¿para qué reformular la pregunta aquí? No me interesa discutirlo aquí, ya está la discusión en Meta. Con el comentario lo único que buscaba era dejar una referencia a la pregunta original.

Comment: Ah, ahora entiendo tu intención. Gracias @MarcosCrispino.

Answer (score 2):

En algunas ocasiones ese error puede solucionarse con el uso de `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0px)` dentro del body o en el cuerpo del elemento, en otras plataformas el uso de `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)` tambien a ayudado a solucionar problemas parecidos.